# Designing the Oxford English Dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked in an interview how I would design the Oxford English Dictionary.

I told him that I'd use a TREE data structure, but he replied that it would take a lot of memory. So which other data structure should be used?

Comment: just a silly thing but doesn't Oxford English Dictionary use instead of mapping world to another word(s) map word to the meaning of word in a few sentences/phrases ? In that case the words coding are the least of your problems and you should think about representing the meaning stuff (words with grammar, and so on) or even consider dictionary based packing like LHARC. Lucky for you English is not very complex in this way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One data structure I heard was used in the past in mobile phones for storing T9 dictionaries is the following (well, this addresses only the key issue, but not the definition storage):

Entries are sorted, and each entry should start with an offset into the previous entry from where it should be continued, and also the continuation. For example:

```
apple
4icable
7tion
```

would decode to apple, applicable, application. However this might not be that different from tries with merged chains, see

```
appl -> e 
     -> ica -> ble
            -> tion
```

Wikipedia uncovered the [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton), which differs from trees that it not only branches, but branches can merge, where words have the same suffix. This indeed could be a superior storage.

```
        a
       / \
  pplic   utom
       \ /
      ation
```

Comment: By the way, wikipedia just told me that "if storing dictionary words is all that is required, a minimal acyclic deterministic finite automaton would use less space than a trie". Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't use a lot of memory. Your answer was fine. Maybe in 1995. Consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if there isn't enough roof for a well-designed trie, there probably isn't room for any other kind of index, either.  Since this is about an interview question, it sounds like he was trying to steer you towards classic out-of-core datastructures like B-trees.

Alternately, a good response might have been to ask for more information, like "what kinds of operations will you want to do on this datastructure, and what kind of performance do you need?"  If you just want a spellcheck, then a Bloom filter might be the most efficient "datastructure"...